# Does there exist a protocol/standard designed for few requests but heavy responses internet browsing

Tags: http, web, web-applications

Suppose an imaginary scenario: the internet requests and responses' count (but not the size of both request and response) is limited for some extraordinary circumstances. For example (to help visualise the problem), suppose requests and the corresponding responses have to be physically delivered by snail mail (traditional mail)

With the traditional mail, the communication typically goes like this: one request, one response. In contrast, the web browsing typically spans tens if not hundreds of requests to load a single page, because the browser needs to load: the page itself, images, javascript, `robots.txt`, css styles and so on.

But is there some sort of a protocol / standard that "packs" the number of requests into one or a few? Things that come to my mind are:

- Convert HTML to PDF
- Print/generage a screenshot of a page

But these seem somewhat amateurish and aren't necessarily made for this exact purpose. For example, they might not capture the interactive elements.

So does there exist a standard according to which the HTML pages are "packable" into a single entity?

Answer (score 1):

After some light searching, I came across a proposed standard that's in the works called [Web Bundles](https://wicg.github.io/webpackage/draft-yasskin-wpack-bundled-exchanges.html). It looks really interesting! It's currently only supported by Chromium-based browsers, and is behind an experiment flag, but it looks like it has lots of potential for a variety of uses. You can read more about it [here on web.dev](https://web.dev/web-bundles/), but I'll include a small snippet from the introduction on that page:

> A Web Bundle is a file format for encapsulating one or more HTTP resources in a single file. It can include one or more HTML files, JavaScript files, images, or stylesheets.
>
> Web Bundles, more formally known as Bundled HTTP Exchanges, are part of the Web Packaging proposal.
>
> HTTP resources in a Web Bundle are indexed by request URLs, and can optionally come with signatures that vouch for the resources. Signatures allow browsers to understand and verify where each resource came from, and treats each as coming from its true origin. This is similar to how Signed HTTP Exchanges, a feature for signing a single HTTP resource, are handled.

Links:

- [Spec proposal repo on Github](https://github.com/WICG/webpackage)
- [Full, Formal proposal draft](https://wicg.github.io/webpackage/draft-yasskin-wpack-bundled-exchanges.html)
- [Introduction on Web.Dev](https://web.dev/web-bundles/)

Answer (score 0):

A person affiliated with [archive.org](https://archive.org) tipped me off about the way IA does that,

> Wayback's captures are stored in WARC format, and there's also the HAR (HTTP Archive) format
>
> WARC is the standard format for storing web archive captures